# Program in GMP Library

Tags: gmp

In Sage, there is a function 'append'. One example is as follows.

```
A=[]
for i in range(100):
   if(i%2==0):
       A.append(i)
```

In  libgmp is there any such kind of function where I can store mpz_t values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. GMP just provides the primitives for mpz_t creation, deletion, and mathmatical operations. Support for data structures is provided by the language that is using libgmp. Sage uses Python as its language for gluing together other libraries and your example is just an example of Python code.